# Azure websites php-cgi error

Tags: php, azure, laravel, laravel-4, azure-web-app-service

On Azure Websites i host a php website made in the laravel framework.
Since a few days, it suddenly stopped working without me having made any changes to the deployment.

Now every time i visit the site i get

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I checked the "DetailedErrors" folder of my log files and found that this was the underlying error:

> D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

but now I'm stuck, is it my fault or is it a bug in their setup?
what can i do more to find a solution.
I also checked the Kudu website of my website but that wasn't much helper either.

Comment: Sounds like a question for your vendor (Azure Support)

Comment: apparently it must have been an issue in their side, i opened the website today and now it's working again